# How to insert pseudo between two div?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I got a tricky situation when I'm inserting pseudo element to the div element. Here's my html structure.

```
<div class="collections-list">
  <div class="collection">...</div>
  <div class="collection">...</div>
  <div class="collection">...</div>
  (where I want to put the pseudo element)
  <div class="collection">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

What I want to do is to add a pseudo element which has `{content: ''}` and other styles. I've tried to use css selector:

```
div.methods-collections-lander div.collection:nth-child(3n)::after
```

But that will insert pseudo element into the div `.collection`. I don't want to create an element and add it between divs because I do want to change the DOM and bind many js functions with it.

Is that possible to use css to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the `order` property.

Unlike the other answers, this answers your question by inserting a pseudo-element into `.collections-list` between `.collection` elements, rather than inserting the pseudo-element into a `.collection` div.

```css
.collections-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.collections-list::after {
  content: 'Pseudo';
  order: 1;
}

.collection:nth-child(n+4) {
  order: 2; /* the 4th and onward .collection elements have a higher order */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="collections-list">
  <div class="collection">1</div>
  <div class="collection">2</div>
  <div class="collection">3</div>
  <div class="collection">4</div>
  <div class="collection">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is  defrent   my and  dippas ans

Comment: @SanjuPrajapati The pseudo-element in my answer is a child of `.collections-list`, rather than a child of one of the `.collection` elements. OP specifically asks for this in the question.

Comment: That's what I need, thanks. Flexbox is a brilliant idea.